# internal RMI registry port issue while running the nokia 6212 emulator

Tags: java, nokia

when i run the nokia 6212 emulator using the eclipse, this error pops out:" The internal RMI    registry port 1099 may be in use by another application.
If the SDK does not start select the Networking tab and enter another internal RMI registry port number". mean time i have uninstalled the jdk7 n install jdk6, this also doesn't gave me any luck. so,if anyone has already face this same problem and has solved it then kindly help me in figuring out the problem.
i am running this emulator on window xp(32-bit).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can check the port number which are in use on your windows machine by command `netstat -ano` on command prompt and get the `PID` of the process using that port, then you can check in task manager which program is using that port

Comment: hi himanshu, my 1099 port number is using by jawaw.exe. evn if i end the jawax.exe process in task manager and again run the emulator, the same error pops out. You have any further solution to solve this, btw thank you soo much for helping me

Comment: Is there any process which is starting it again, after you killed it ?

Comment: These are the 2 websites it can help you can have look at them  http://code-gotcha.blogspot.in/2011/11/rmi-registry-port-may-be-used-error.html and http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?230026-Help-a-internal-RMI-registry-port-number

Comment: Hi, actually i am writing some code for NFC in java, through that project only iam trying to startup the emulator, so i check out the PID in command prompt and that PID is using by javaw.exe, so, i guess there won't be any issue because iam running the java project. but the same error is pops out when i started the emulator after killing the javaw.exe.
btw, there is no process when it kills and started. so, any further solutions

Comment: a port can be used only once by a server. so look up the docs on how to change the port and choose another port like 10501 a port can be an int from 1 to 65000 but generally we choose over 1,0000 where we can as the under 1,000s are used by famous apps (like 80, 443, 8080, 8443 for web & ssl...)

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue of jre. Only the 32 bit version of jre 7 update 17 seems to work wel for these emulators. Source: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/230026-Help-a-internal-RMI-registry-port-number

Comment: What known issue of the JRE? Sounds more like an issue of the emulator. Link broken.